# Align an image with a div?

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to center my text vertically in the div and then slide the div on the centered right side of the picture as show in example:

[image]

I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
    <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="logo"/>
    </div> 
    <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="$HOME_PAGE_LINK$">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="headerPro">
    <div class="headerAvatar">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/DQBOgkw.png" alt="avatar" />
    </div>
    <div class="headerText">
        This is some text.
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#headerPro {
     position:absolute;
     top: 35px;
     right: 50px;
     width:450px;
     height:100px;
    }
    .headerAvatar {
     margin-top:10px;
     margin-left:150px;
     background: #242426;
     width: 70px;
     height: 70px;
     padding: 5px;
     border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .headerAvatar img{
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     border: 0;
     margin: 0; 
     border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .headerText {
     height:50px;
     width:200px;
     text-align:center;
     background-color:red;
    }
```

Comment: You need to wrap the image div and text divs in ANOTHER div, and center that wrapper. e.g. position the #headerPro.

Comment: Is this what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/VpG6s/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the float property :

Set your image div to inline :

```
.headerAvatar { display: inline-block; }
```

and then float the text :

```
.headerText { float: right }
```

Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/nDXMr/

Note : I put some margin-top to vertically align the 2 div's.

Answer (score 1):

I editted RoyalLys' jsfiddle and added:

```
 .headerText{
  line-height:50px;
 }
```

This **vertically centers** the text in the div

http://jsfiddle.net/nDXMr/1/

Also, take a look at one of my old questions. It is not 100% the same, but might give you the answer:

[HTML and CSS3 menu questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895082/html-and-css3-menu-questions)

**EDIT:**
I made a jsfiddle of your code and added some things:

```
float:left;
```

on #nav, .headerAvatar, .headerText

```
 margin-top:20px;
 line-height:50px;
```

on the .headerText

You can add some other margins to add space between the different elements.

jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fL4JA/

Answer (score 0):

You could also add something like this to your headerText class:

```
 top: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
```